# Mysql Match Against Agro

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, match

I'm having some trouble querying a database of scrapped movie titles – alternate spellings & misspellings are the most common headache.

Let's say I already have "Le weekend" in the database, and then another theatre has a film called "Le Week-End". I don't want duplicates in my database, so I need to compare.

I start by checking to see if the exact title is already in the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM films WHERE original LIKE 'Le Week-End'";
```

No hit, obviously. I set "Le Week-End" up for boolean search and try a MATCH query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM films WHERE MATCH(original) AGAINST ('+le +week +end')";
```

No hit. Now what?

I realise that full text searching is very involved, but I've been trying to sort this out to no avail. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried `trimming` the data before comparing.. it may be that there is extra space present.

Comment: Ended up going for levensheint matching - working pretty well so far.